# SSIS Error: Unable to retrieve destination column descriptions from the parameters of the SQL command

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, triggers, etl

[image: SSIS task]

I am getting an error :

> [Load updated records to Table_vwAs_FixedIdentifier [85]] Error: Unable to retrieve destination column descriptions from the parameters of the SQL command.

when I execute the SSIS task in the image. It fails on the lower left "Load updated records to Table_vwAs.." oleDb update task. It has the following sql statement and also has a trigger also shown below. I have not been able to identify the cause of this issue till now. **When I disabled the trigger, the task ran successfully**. Any help will be eye-opening.

```
UPDATE
  [dbo].[Sec]
SET
       [SecID]=?
      ,[SECURITY_NAME]=?
      ,[SECURITY_SECTYPE_ID]=?
      ,[SECURITY_EXCHANGE_ID]=?      
WHERE
  [MasterID]=?
```

Trigger code is as follows:

```
alter trigger [dbo].[TrTable_Fixed_AFTERUPDATE] on [dbo].[Sec]
after insert ,update
as
set NOCOUNT on

declare @DBMailDistributionListId varchar(50)
declare @ProfileName varchar(max)
declare @Recipients varchar(max)
declare @CopyRecipients varchar(max)
declare @BlindCopyRecipients varchar(max)
set @DBMailDistributionListId = 'Crossadyne1'
set @ProfileName = SharedCode.dbo.FnGetDBMailDistributionListProfileName(@DBMailDistributionListId)
set @Recipients = SharedCode.dbo.FnGetDBMailDistributionListRecipients(@DBMailDistributionListId)
set @CopyRecipients = SharedCode.dbo.FnGetDBMailDistributionListCopyRecipients(@DBMailDistributionListId)
set @BlindCopyRecipients = SharedCode.dbo.FnGetDBMailDistributionListBlindCopyRecipients(@DBMailDistributionListId)

declare @Subject varchar(max)
declare @Body varchar(max)
set @Body = ''

select distinct @Body = @Body + 'Master Sec ID: ' + convert(nvarchar(50) ,i.MasterId) + char(13) + char(10)
        + 'New Legal Entity ID: ' + convert(nvarchar(50) ,i.[INTERNAL_SECURITY_LEGALENTITY_ID])           
    from INSERTED i 
        inner join DELETED d
        on i.MasterId = d.MasterId
    where i.[INTERNAL_SECURITY_LEGALENTITY_ID] <> d.[INTERNAL_SECURITY_LEGALENTITY_ID]
        and i.Security_Change_Date = i.LegalEntityChangeDate
        and i.LegalEntityChangedBy not in (2 ,5)

if (@Body <> '') 
    begin

        set @Subject = 'WARNING: Crossadyne Security Legal Entity changed'

        exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = @ProfileName
          , @recipients = @Recipients
          , @copy_recipients = @CopyRecipients
          , @blind_copy_recipients = @BlindCopyRecipients
          , @subject = @Subject
          , @body = @Body

    end


set @DBMailDistributionListId = 'test'
set @ProfileName = SharedCode.dbo.FnGetDBMailDistributionListProfileName(@DBMailDistributionListId)
set @Recipients = SharedCode.dbo.FnGetDBMailDistributionListRecipients(@DBMailDistributionListId)
set @CopyRecipients = SharedCode.dbo.FnGetDBMailDistributionListCopyRecipients(@DBMailDistributionListId)
set @BlindCopyRecipients = SharedCode.dbo.FnGetDBMailDistributionListBlindCopyRecipients(@DBMailDistributionListId)

set @Body = ''

select distinct @Body = @Body + 'Master ID: ' + convert(nvarchar(50) ,i.MasterId) + char(13) + char(10)            
        + 'Previous Legal Entity ID: ' + convert(nvarchar(50) ,d.[INTERNAL_SECURITY_LEGALENTITY_ID])           
    from INSERTED i 
        inner join DELETED d
        on i.MasterId = d.MasterId
    where i.[INTERNAL_SECURITY_ID] <> d.[INTERNAL_SECURITY_LEGALENTITY_ID]

if (@Body <> '') 
    begin

        set @Subject = 'WARNING: Crossadyne Security Legal Entity changed'

        exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = @ProfileName
          , @recipients = @Recipients
          , @copy_recipients = @CopyRecipients
          , @blind_copy_recipients = @BlindCopyRecipients
          , @subject = @Subject
          , @body = @Body

    end

set NOCOUNT off
```

Comment: I think there is an error posted above the error you mentioned

Comment: Why are you showing us a trigger on `Table_Fixed` if your UPDATE is on `Sec`?

Comment: Thanks Tab. I made a mistake while renaming some entities before posting to a public forum. my bad and its been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was being caused due to
`exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`
in the trigger code, because it is not configured on the QA server. Resolved after I commented those lines.